# how to pass tablename from cursor in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to take counts of all the tables with some conditions,  that are fetched using the cursor.

I am unable to pass cursor as table name in plsql block

code :

```
create or replace procedure find_tables
is
cursor tba_tables_cur is
    select table_name from all tables where owner='ABC';

type tba_tbl is record ( table_name varchar2 (128));
type var_table_name is table of tba_tbl;
var_table_name_rec var_table_name;
l_array_size number default 1000;
v_count number;

begin

    open tba_tables_cur;
    loop 
    fetch tba_tables_cur into var_table_name_rec limit l_array_size;
    forall i in 1 .. var_table_name_rec.count 
            select count(*) from var_table_name_rec(i) where flag ='Y' into v_count;

    if (v_count >0)
    then
        dbms_output.put_line(v_count);
    end_if;

exit when tba_tables_cur%notfound;
end loop;
close tba_tables_cur;

end;
```

I am facing errors like unidentified tablename etc

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` here -

```
create or replace procedure find_tables
is
  cursor tba_tables_cur is
     select owner, table_name from all_tables where owner='SYS';

  type tba_tbl is record ( owner_name varchar2(128),
                           table_name varchar2 (128));
  type var_table_name is table of tba_tbl;
  var_table_name_rec var_table_name;
  l_array_size number default 1000;
  v_count      number;
  query        varchar2(500);

begin

    open tba_tables_cur;
          loop 
      fetch tba_tables_cur bulk collect into var_table_name_rec limit l_array_size;
      for i in 1 .. var_table_name_rec.count loop
        query := 'select count(*) from ' || 
                  var_table_name_rec(i).owner_name ||
                  '.' ||
                  var_table_name_rec(i).table_name ||
                  ' where flag =''Y''';
        execute immediate query into v_count;

        if (v_count >0) then
          dbms_output.put_line(v_count);
        end if;
       end loop;
  exit when tba_tables_cur%notfound;
  end loop;
  close tba_tables_cur;

end;
/
```

[DB Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ac76694a3af5d61cbb2033f04d9128dd)

Comment: I am facing below errors. can you please assist                                                                   --Error(17,33): PLS-00597: expression 'VAR_TABLE_NAME_REC' in the INTO list is of wrong type
--Error(19,18): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'

Comment: No. You cannot prefix a local variable with the schema name they only exist within the block. A  schema prefix would be used to references database objects. If you have a different user that would be a parameter and be used as "where owner = *parameter*".

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: I have added schema name in query := 'select count(*) from <schema_name>' || var_table_name_rec(i).table_name || ' where flag =''Y''';   However I am having problem with loop. I have about 2000+ tables in cursor whereas dbmsouput.put_line is printing only 4 tables with count. I have commented the if condition to see counts of all tables.

Comment: Please try with the updated code. If you still have some issues please post your updated code.

Comment: Thank You very much for assitance. I figured this was due to insufficient privielege for user running the procedure. The old code was perfectly alright. Apologies for inconvenience.]

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be that complex? How about something simpler?

In order to satisfy the "condition" *condition*, I'm fetching tables that contain column which makes that *condition* - the `EMPNO` column. Then you'd

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(200); -- to compose a SELECT statement
  3    l_cnt number;        -- contains number of rows in a table
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select c.table_name
  6                  from user_tab_columns c
  7                  where c.column_name = 'EMPNO'
  8                 )
  9    loop
 10      l_str := 'select count(*) from ' || cur_r.table_name ||
 11               ' where empno is not null';    --> that's your "condition"
 12      execute immediate l_str into l_cnt;
 13
 14      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.table_name ||': '|| l_cnt);
 15    end loop;
 16  end;
 17  /
EMP: 14
BONUS: 0
EMP_1: 3
EMP_2: 5
EMP_3: 6

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I have added schema name here in query l_str := 'select count(*) from <schema_name>.' || cur_r.table_name ||' where empno is not null'; however I am not seeing any output in sql developer. I have enabled dbms ouput with connection name that I am using. system only throws "plsql procedure successfully executed" but not the variable output. am I missing anything ??

Comment: Don't EXECUTE IMMEDIATE L_STR, but **first** DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_STR) so that you'd see what you're actually executing. Then run that SELECT statement and see what it returns (if anything).

Comment: sorry. I have added set serveroutput on; in session and it worked. However I am having problem with loop. I have about 2000+ tables in cursor whereas dbmsouput.put_line is printing only 4 tables with count.

Comment: It means that there are only 4 of them which satisfy the condition. That's what your `if (v_count >0) then ...` says - display only if you find something; don't display anything if there's nothing found.

Comment: Post your current code so that we'd see what you have.

Comment: Thank You very much for assitance. I figured this was due to insufficient privielege for user running the procedure.